# Why my nodejs request is saving data from last request and 1 time late?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I will try my best to explain the situation.

Let say there are 4 patch requests made to `/inventorys/users/:inventoryId`. with the data from body.

These are the 4 requests with body data.

```
REQUEST1 => { users: 65ef2d09ef674c1e1a3632e5 }

REQUEST2 => { users: 65ef2d09ef674c1e1a3632e5 }

REQUEST3 => { users: 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9 }

REQUEST4 => { users: 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9 }
```

In my database I want to `add or remove user` from the inventory.

Here is the code

```
router.patch("/inventorys/users/:inventoryId", auth, async (req, res) => {  
  try {
    //check if inventory exist and 
    const inventory = await Inventory.findOne({
      _id: req.params.inventoryId
    });

    if (!inventory) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: "Inventory not found" });
    }

    // check if user exist in the data base.
    const newUserOrOldUser = await User.findOne({
      _id: req.body.users,
    });


    // Check if user already exist users array
    const userIndex = inventory.users.findIndex((userId) =>
      userId.equals(req.body.users)
    );

    // new user
    if (userIndex === -1) {
      await Inventory.updateOne(
        { _id: inventory._id },
        { $push: { users: req.body.users } }
      );
      console.log("add user", req.body.users, req.user._id);
    } else {
      await Inventory.updateOne(
        { _id: inventory._id },
        { $pull: { users: req.body.users } }
      );
      console.log("remove user", req.body.users);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(inventory);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
});
```

Before making those 4 request at top. I **delete** all users from the inventory array manually.

Here is the console that comes out when i made those request

```
remove user 65ef2d09ef674c1e1a3632e5
add user 65ef2d09ef674c1e1a3632e5
add user 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9
remove user 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9
```

As you can see from the `first request` It saying the user is removed. but the res.send is actually sending me the added data.

For the `second request` It saying added user but the users array is now empty.

For the `Third request` This is **the weird part**. Its saying add user `add user 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9` but the data send back is with `65ef2d09ef674c1e1a3632e5` in the user array. So idk how the user from last request is added in this request.

Now for the `4th request`. Its saying `remove user 65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9` but now its adding the user `65ef2d11ef674c1e1a3632e9` because this user is not in the array yet.

So at the end of `4 request` the users array got `2 users`. Its should be empty

Comment: I think the weird part is allready in the first request: You said you manually emptied the `inventory.users` array (whatever that means exactly). So how can the first request result into a `remove`? Typically, it can only remove a value it found (ie `index !== -1`), but how can it find something in an empty array? This is a typical case where you need to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger and step through your backendcode to see what is really happening ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```js
const userIndex = inventory.users.findIndex((userId) =>
   userId.equals(req.body.users)
);
```

You are using a non standard `equals()` function so your code could well be erroring here. By that I mean you expect to get a `-1` when the `inventory.users` is an empty array or the value is not in the array but it is likely that `userIndex` is not what you expect.

Here is some code that could better achieve your desired outcome

```js
router.patch("/inventorys/users/:inventoryId", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // 1. check if user exist in the database.
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
            _id: req.body.users,
        });
        // 1.1 Return error as no user exits
        if (!existingUser) {
            return res.status(404).send({ error: "User not found" });
        }
        
        // 2. check if inventory exist 
        const inventory = await Inventory.findOne({
            _id: req.params.inventoryId
        });
        // 2.1 Return error as no inventory exits
        if (!inventory) {
            return res.status(404).send({ error: "Inventory not found" });
        }
        
        //
        // At this stage we know that we have an existingUser && inventory otherwise it would have returned
        //
        
        // 3. Check if inventory exits with this user
        const inventoryWithUser = await Inventory.findOne({
            _id: req.params.inventoryId,
            users: req.body.users
        })
 
        if (!inventoryWithUser) {
            // 3.1.a  We now know that we have an existingUser && inventory but the user IS NOT in this inventory
            // So we can push the existingUser to the inventory.users array we got earlier
            inventory.users.push(req.body.users);
            await inventory.save();
            console.log("User ADDED to inventory", req.body.users, req.user._id);
            return res.status(200).send(inventory);
        }else{
            // 3.1.b  We now know that we have an existingUser && inventory AND the user IS in the inventory
            // So we can pull it from the inventoryWithUser.users array
            inventoryWithUser.users.pull(req.body.users);
            await inventoryWithUser.save();
            console.log("User REMOVED from inventory", req.body.users, req.user._id);
            return res.status(200).send(inventoryWithUser);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the stale state of your `inventory` variable. You are fetching the inventory at the start of the request, and never updating it. You do use the `inventory` variable across various conditions and DB operations, but you aren't updating it whatsoever.

You should do one of the following:

1. Update the `inventory` variable locally whenever you make a change
2. Fetch the updated state of the Inventory before you send the response, and update the `inventory` variable.

Let me know if this helps!